# Applying Math.min() to an empty list produces -Infinity instead of 0

Tags: javascript, forms

I have developed a code in which adds values and at the end subtracts the smallest value based on the items you select in a form. The code works fine however the problem occurs when you unselect all the items and instead of displaying 0, it displays -Infinity. What do I do to this script to force it to display 0 instead of -Infinity?

```
// All selected prices are stored on a array
var prices = [];

// A function to remove a item from an array
function remove(array, item) {
    for (var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (array[i] == item) {
            array.splice(i, 1);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function calculateSectedDues(checkbox, amount) {
    // We add or remove the price as necesary

    if (checkbox.checked) {
        prices.push(amount);
    } else {
        remove(prices, amount);
    }

    // We sum all the prices
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0, len = prices.length; i < len; i++)
        total += prices[i];

    // We get the lower one
    var min = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);

    // And substract it
    total -= min;

    // Please, don't access the DOM elements this way, use document.getElementById instead
    document.grad_enroll_form.total.value = total;

}


</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Math.min()` with no arguments returns `Infinity`, which is what happens when you call `Math.min.apply(Math, prices)` with an empty `prices` array.

Why not just detect the presence of an `Infinity` minimum and reset it to zero?

```
// We get the lower one
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);

// ** test for Infinity **
if(min == Infinity) { min = 0; }

// And substract it
total -= min;
```

Or make sure `prices` has at least one element:

```
// fill the empty array with a zero
if(prices.length == 0) prices.push(0);

// We get the lower one
var min = Math.min.apply(Math, prices);
```

Comment: @Alfie_Fitz Trailing zeros are dropped in JavaScript. You can use `.toFixed(2)` to show the number as a string with two decimal places. (Take a look at [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken) to understand general problems with floating point numbers.)